# Counting how many properties with a typeof value of 'object' are inside another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration, each

I've been doing some iterations to obtain a certain amount of values.

```
            $.each(Obj, function(k,v){
                $.each(v, function(j,l){
                    $.each(l, function(r,s){
                        if(l.hasOwnProperty(r) && typeof s === 'object'){

                        }
                    })
                })
            })
```

In this code, you'll see that I'm iterating over an object named "Obj". Inside of it we'll have a few amount of arrays and objects, because is a very complex structure. But let's cut the chatter. Once we arrive to this part...

```
           $.each(l, function(r,s){
                if(l.hasOwnProperty(r) && typeof s === 'object'){

                }
            })
```

You'll see that we have a conditional. In that conditional I'm checking for those properties "r" that have a typeof value of 'object'. So, if I do a console check of "r" inside my conditional, I will actually see those specific properties.

So, here's the thing. Why am I doing this? Well I'm building a variable that will ONLY store those "l" elements that have a child property with 'object' as a typeof value. That's actually working, but the problem is that, for my purposes, I need this variable not only to work as intended, but also to store only the elements that have MORE THAN ONE property with 'object' as a typeof value.

So, let's consider this case:

If I have two objects like the following...

```
Obj1: [{"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"[{"key":"value", "key":"value"}, { "key":"value", "key":"value"}]"}]

Obj1: [{"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"[{"key":"value", "key":"value"}, { "key":"value", "key":"value"}]", "key":"[{"key":"value", "key":"value"}, { "key":"value", "key":"value"}]"}]
```

I want my variable to store ONLY the second one, because it has 2 values with objects inside of it.

So, In my conditional I would like to use some kind of logic that let me know not only if my "l" element has an object inside of it, but also, how many of them do I have, and if they're lesser than one, then my console log shouldn't bring them up.

Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is to design something that would be recursive and would not blow the stack:

```
    function inspect (obj,f,e,ledger) {
/*obj is the object to inspect,
f is the call back,
e is an internal reference to setTimeout,
ledger is the array that will be populated*/
                var ledger = ledger || [],
                    probObjCount = 0;
                f = f || false,
                e && e.value ? clearTimeout(e.value) : void(0);
                e = e || {};
                e.value = setTimeout(function(){f && f.call(ledger,ledger);},50);
                if(obj instanceof Array){
                    obj.forEach(function(d,i){
                        (typeof d === "object") && window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                            inspect(d,f,e,ledger);
                        })
                    })
                    return;
                }
                for (var i in obj) {
                    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(typeof obj[i] === "object") {
                        ++probObjCount;
                        !function(obj){
                            window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                                inspect(obj,f,e,ledger);
                            })
                        }(obj[i]);
                    }
                }
                if(probObjCount >= 2){
                    ledger.push(obj);
                }
            }
```

You provide this function 2 things, an object to inspect and a callback that will be provided with a ledger (an array) that will be the list of objects that fits your criteria:

```
var x = [{"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":[{"key4":"value", "key5":"value"}, { "key6":"value", "key7":"value"}]}];
inspect(x,function(l){console.log(l)});
//after a few seconds:
//[]

var x = [{"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":[{"key4":"value", "key5":"value"}, { "key6":"value", "key7":"value"}], "key8":[{"key9":"value", "key10":"value"}, { "key11":"value", "key12":"value"}]}]
inspect(x,function(l){console.log(l)});
//[{…}]
```

Above 2 are your examples, now I will turn your 1st example into an example that would be accepted:

```
var x = [{"key1":"value", "key2":"value", "key3":[{"key4":["value"], "key5":["value"]}, { "key6":"value", "key7":"value"}]}]
inspect(x,function(l){console.log(l)});
//[{…}] you will get {"key4":["value"], "key5":["value"]}
```

Comment: This worked exceptionally good! Thanks, I've been burning my head for hours.